# Redirect all requests to base URL without using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

When I browse ***example.com/img*** it shows all the **directory contents**. This leads to security problem . How to **redirect** these kind of url requests to *example.com* **but without using htaccess**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice usually suggests adding these lines to your Apache config to disable directory listing:

```
<Directory />
  Options -Indexes
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But this will simply deny users access to the URL example.com/img. If you'd like to redirect as well, you could add an `index.php` file to each directory you'd like to redirect from in addition to making the Apache config change. The `index.php` file should contain:

```
<?php
header("Location:".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```